# How to use Thread in the button below

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0, thread-safety

When I press the button, decoding a Qrcode works well but I want to do it with a Thread.
I wrote like below but the thread doesn't work.
Does anyone know, how can i fix it?
Thanks.
Here is my code:

```cs
private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users...\1.jpg");
        MessagingToolkit.QRCode.Codec.QRCodeDecoder decoder = new MessagingToolkit.QRCode.Codec.QRCodeDecoder();
        textBox2.Text = decoder.Decode(new QRCodeBitmapImage(pictureBox1.Image as Bitmap));
    });
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I update the GUI from another thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-do-i-update-the-gui-from-another-thread)

Comment: why are accessing an UI element "textBox2.Text" from another thread

Comment: @ErwinDraconis it is not uncommon to offload some cpu bound work to another thread and then update the UI when it is done.

Comment: @ErwinDraconis
i added new textbox3 just right now but it still has the same problem:
This is the error message:
Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'textBox3' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.'

Comment: If the image for your picturebox is always the same, then load it into your app as an **embedded resource**, or possibly an ImageList.  If the QR decoder gets used in multiple places, then declare it at class/form level and re-use the same instance of creating a new one each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update the `TextBox` after the completion of the `Task`, at a point where you are back to the UI thread.

```
private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var bitmap = await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        return (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users...\1.jpg");
    });
    pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;
    var result = await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var decoder = new MessagingToolkit.QRCode.Codec.QRCodeDecoder();
        return decoder.Decode(new QRCodeBitmapImage(bitmap));
    });
    textBox2.Text = result;
}
```

---

**Update:** The code that updates the `PictureBox` should be moved out of the `Task.Run` body too.

---

**Update:** The loading of image can block the UI too, so I moved it in a separate `Task`.

Comment: @arash6657 I updated my answer because there is another potential issue with the `pictureBox1`.

Comment: @arash6657 my advice is to set the property [`Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls` = true;](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.checkforillegalcrossthreadcalls) at the start of your program (before `Application.Run`), to check for other problems that may have passed unnoticed. Personally I always set this property on Debug mode. I don't set it on Release mode because it has a performance overhead.

Comment: Thanks for the update code but it still has a problem. as you mentioned it block the UI. but with the new code, it showed me this error:
Object is currently in use elsewhere.'

Comment: @arash6657 Hmm, it is possible that the `pictureBox1` locks the image. Could you try `pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(bitmap);`?

Comment: Thanks, yes it works well but i would like also to delete the image at the end of the process and it showed me the error :"it is being used by another process
", Could you please tell how to fix it also?
Thankss
i added the code below at the end:
            if (File.Exists(@"C:\Users...\1.jpg"))
            {
                File.Delete(@"C:\Users...\1.jpg");

            }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202902/discussion-between-arash6657-and-theodor-zoulias).

Answer (score 2):

This will keep your UI responsive

```
private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var Result = await Decode("Image Path");

        textBox2.Text = Result;
    }

    private async Task<string> Decode(string PathOfImage)
    {
        var DecodedText = string.Empty;
        var decoder = new MessagingToolkit.QRCode.Codec.QRCodeDecoder();

        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            DecodedText = decoder.Decode(new QRCodeBitmapImage(Image.FromFile(PathOfImage) as Bitmap));
        });

        return DecodedText;
    }
```

Update 2 : here is how you can do it in one function :

```
private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var DecodedText = string.Empty;
        var decoder = new MessagingToolkit.QRCode.Codec.QRCodeDecoder();

        await Task.Run(() => {
            DecodedText = decoder.Decode(new QRCodeBitmapImage(Image.FromFile(PathOfImage) as Bitmap));
        });

        textBox2.Text = DecodedText;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it has an error with the word "Image" in the line :
"Image.FromFile(...)"
i guess one "=" is extra but even with removing the second "=" it shows an error with the word "Image"

Comment: @gromit190
Thanks for the answer but it has an error with the word "Image" in the line : "Image.FromFile(...)" i guess one "=" is extra but even with removing the second "=" it shows an error with the word "Image"

Comment: @arash6657 im not sur why you get this exception, try to pass Image.FromFile(PathOfImage) directly to the QRCodeBitmapImage constructor, see the edited answer

Comment: Thanks for the updated code. it works pretty well :)
just one more question, is it also possible to write it easier in one function? (sth like what i wrote but it didn't work)

Answer (score -1):

The dispatcher object is used to modify the UI from a thread or a Task

**Below how to use a Task**

Method 1

```
bool result ;
Task<bool> task = Task.Run<bool>(async () => await RefreshUIAsync());
str = task.Result;

public async Task<bool> RefreshUIAsync()
{
   bool result;
   result= await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => RefreshUI());
   return result;
}

private string RefreshUI()
{           
  bool result;
  try
  {
     this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (ThreadStart)delegate()
    {   
      string ImagePath="";
      pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(ImagePath);
      .......
    });
    result=true;
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
      result=false;
  }  
 return result;
}
```

Method 2

```
RefreshUIAsync().Wait();  

public async Task RefreshUIAsync()
{
   await Task.Run(() => {
   This.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (ThreadStart)delegate()
    {   
      string ImagePath="";
      pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(ImagePath);
      .......
    });
   });
}
```

**And below how to use a Thread**

Method 1

```
myThread = new Thread(() => ThreaRefreshUI());
myThread.Start();

private void ThreaRefreshUI()
{

    try
    {
    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (ThreadStart)delegate()
    {   
      string ImagePath="";
      pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(ImagePath);
      .......
    });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Method 2

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreaRefreshUI));
thread.Start();

 public void ThreaRefreshUI()
 {
   try
   {
    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (ThreadStart)delegate()
    {   
      string ImagePath="";
      pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(ImagePath);
      .......
    });
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {

   }
 }
```

Method 3

```
 Thread thread = new Thread(ThreaRefreshUI);
 thread.Start();

 public void ThreaRefreshUI()
 {
   try
   {
    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (ThreadStart)delegate()
    {   
      string ImagePath="";
      pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(ImagePath);
      .......
    });
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {

   }
 }
```